# car loan instalment calculator javascript

Tags: javascript, html

this is my coding that im working to calculate instalment for car loan. but it seems my calculate button not working. i dont know what is my mistake. if anybody could help that would be nice.
newbie programmer here.

```
    <table>
        <tr><td> Car Price (RM): </td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "txtPrice" size = "10" onchange="calculate();"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td> (Retail Purchase Price) </td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td> Down Payment (RM): </td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "txtDownPayment" size = "10" onchange="calculate();"></td>
            <td> (minimum of 10% of car price) </td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td> Interest Rate (%): </td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "txtInterest" size = "10" onchange="calculate();"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td> Loan Duration: </td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "txtDuration" size = "5" onchange="calculate();"></td>
            <td> (year) </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br>
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type = "button" value = "Calculate" onClick = "calculate();"></td>
            <td> RM </td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "txtLoanInstallment" size =  "10"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script language = "JavaScript">
    function calculate()
    {
        var price, downPayment, interest, duration, tenPercent, loan, totalLoan;
        price = parseDouble (document.form1.txtPrice.value);
        downPayment = parseDouble (document.form1.txtDownPayment.value);
        interest = parseDouble (document.form1.txtInterest.value);
        duration = parseInt (document.form1.txtDuration.value);
        tenPercent = (downPayment/price * 10);
        loan = price - tenPercent;
        totalLoan = (loan + (loan * interest*0.01) * duration) / (duration * 12);
        document.form1.txtLoanInstallment.value = totalLoan.toFixed(2);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: On a side note you should really do some validating to make sure that the user is actually entering something that can be parsed, then do calculations on it. Try using `parseFloat()` instead of `parseDouble()`. If you open your dev tools what errors are you getting?

Comment: Exactly what does "now working" mean? Have you tried debugging? What errors do you get?

Comment: im using notepad++ and i think there is no error. but i will try using parseFloat() as you suggest. thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah if you are using chrome of fireforx or safari, use the console to see if what types of errors are you getting and post them in your answer

Comment: nice. it solve now. im just changing parseDouble() to parseFloat() and its working. thanks senior.
@j08691 my calculate button not calculate the process.